# Convert displacement to polygons

Tags: modeling, displacement

iam dealing with this problem. I try to change from Maya to Blender and one thing is making me nuts. The displacement. I use it a lot to create geometry. So far I could not handle that in blender.
Is there any advice to do this properly?

There are three pictures, in the first one i try displacement texture but it does not affect the geometry at all and I dont now how to convert it.
Second one is how its done in Maya and how i do this.
Third one is done via modificator which happend to be bad.

[image: My displacement texture isnt affecting the geometry and probably cant by convertet to it]
[image: This is how its don in Maya]

[image: trying to use modifier]

Comment: what you're looking for is probably third picture (Displacement modifier) but maybe share your file so that we understand why it doesn't give the expected result: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the added displacement modifier result image. Could you add your blend file with the texture in it? As if I roughly copy it from the image above, I've this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gNoE.jpg

Comment: it can be downloaded here [link](https://we.tl/t-EXBgATB6fq), its just the cube with prepared displacement map

Comment: @lemon your displacement seems to be working as expected, what Iam missing

Comment: as you're using the cube's UV, in the modifier you need to choose Texture Coordinates > UV

Comment: @moonboots, just gave you the answer!

Comment: Aslo, reduce the modifier's Strength, and put one Subsurf above and one under the Displacement with subdivisions of 2.

Comment: @moonboots oh shit thats it, just to switch to the UV coordinates and iam looking for solutions on every forum possible for two days. What exactly is that helping to have that modifier below and abow?

And completeli out of the problem, dont you know why the texture displacement is not showing like in space? that it is still just 2D affecting the shadows

Comment: And you should set mid level to 0 to avoid the effect on the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using the cube's UV, in the modifier you need to choose *Texture Coordinates* > *UV*. Also, reduce the modifier's *Strength*, and put one *Subsurf* above and one under the *Displacement* with subdivisions of 2, this will make it smooth nicely.

[image]